I made a complex number command
So I've written a command as a homework assignment to render complex numbers correctly. Like, when I write \complfull{5}{-2} the output is 5-2i
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}    %this package is needed for the if else commands like \IfStrEq

\newcommand{\complfull}[2]{     %This bracket covers the case for when the real part is zero
    \IfStrEq{#1}{0}{\IfStrEqCase{#2}{
        {0}         {0}                 %"If b is also zero, output zero"
        {1}         {i}     %"If b is just one, output 'i'(instead of '1i')"
        {-1}        {-i}}
    [#2\textit{i}]}{\IfStrEqCase{#2}{   %This bracket is the first command's "else" statement, so it covers the case when the real part is not zero
        {0}         {#1}                %"If the imaginary part is zero, output the real part"
        {1}         {#1+i}
        {-1}        {#1-i}}
    [\IfBeginWith{#2}{-}                %This covers the case when the imaginary part is negative and the real part is not zero. It is necessary because we can't have a number be displayed as "1+-4i", and doing it with brackets would necessitate every imaginary part to be written with brackets.
        {#1#2i}
        {#1+#2i}]}
}

\begin{document}
    
    \complfull{2}{-2}
    \complfull{0}{1}

\end{document}

This code gives me an error message for inputs like $\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3}$
These are the error messages:
Undefined control sequence. $\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3}

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000]. $\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3}

However, when I do something like $\displaystyle\complfull{\frac{1}{2}}{-1}$ it works just fine.
What is causing the problem?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Please extend your example to a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. Why all these \textit commands here? Personally I do not really see the point is making something as "complex" as this.

Note that after adding amsmath (\dfrac is not defined in plain latex) I get a different error.

If you're posting error messages, please copy them verbatimly from the log and not from some error summary provided by your editor. The formatting of an Undefined control sequence error tells you which was the undefined control sequence (the last token in the first line). In error summaries this information tends to get lost.

Look at \complexnum macro proposed by the siunitx package for numeric cases.

The answer for your question: the $\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3}$ generates error because your \complull macro applies \IfStrEq to its arguments and \IfStrEq expands them during processing by \edef. And the \dfrac macro isn't defined as \protected\def. It uses an old and obscure \protect LaTeX method which doesn't work with \edef.
The problem, you are solving, is interesting. I show, what we can do with OpTeX:
\def\complfull#1#2{%
   \isequal{#1}{0}\iftrue \printimpart\empty{#2}%
                  \else {#1}\printimpart+{#2}%
                  \fi
}
\def\printimpart#1#2{%
   \qcasesof {#2}
   {}      {\ifx#1\empty 0\fi}
   {0}     {\ifx#1\empty 0\fi}
   {1}     {#1\imu}
   {-1}    {-\imu}
   \_finc  {\isminus #2\iftrue \else #1\fi {#2}\imu}%
}
\def\imu{{\rm i}}
\def\isminus #1#2\iftrue{\ifx-#1}

Test:
$\complfull{1}{0}; 
\complfull{0}{};
\complfull{0}{1}; 
\complfull{0}{-1};  
\complfull{1}{1}, 
\complfull{1}{-1}; 
\complfull{1\over2}{1\over2},
\complfull{1\over2}{-{1\over2}};
\complfull{-1\over12}{\exp(7)},$

\bye

The \complfull macro is fully expandable and it doesn't expands its arguments when \isequal or \qcasesof macros are processed.

Switching to a diffent testing method and cleaning up the code (I see no reason to use \textit{i} here as i is already italic in math mode.
I'm sure this can be done even simpler. Version now no longer uses anything from xstring as their tests are rather fragile.
The use of \NewDocumentCommand{\complfull}{m >{\TrimSpaces} m}{ make sure that #2 never starts with a space, as that would break the test to see if the imaginary part starts with -.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% this assumes the arg never starts with spaces
\def\ProcessFirstChar#1#2\END{%
  \def\FirstChar{#1}
}
\def\DASHCHAR{-}

% input a,b, need to generate z = a+bi in a nice way
\NewDocumentCommand{\complfull}{m >{\TrimSpaces} m}{
  % if a =0
  \ifstrequal{#1}{0}{
      \ifstrequal{#2}{0}{
          0
        }{
          \ifstrequal{#2}{1}{
              i
            }{
              \ifstrequal{#2}{-1}{
                  -i
                }{ 
                  #2i% default
                }
            }
        }
    }{
      % a is not zero
      #1% just leave a
      \ifstrequal{#2}{0}{%
          % Im(z) = 0, so nothing
        }{
          \ifstrequal{#2}{1}{
              + i
            }{
              \ifstrequal{#2}{-1}{
                  -i
                }{
                  % still need the case when b is negative, as we should not add a plus in this case
                  \expandafter\ProcessFirstChar#2\END
                  \ifx\FirstChar\DASHCHAR\else+\fi
                  #2i
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

\begin{document}


$\complfull{0}{0}$

$\complfull{0}{1}$

$\complfull{0}{-1}$

$\complfull{0}{5}$

$\complfull{1}{0}$

$\complfull{1}{1}$

$\complfull{1}{-1}$

$\complfull{1}{5}$

$\complfull{1}{-5}$

$\complfull{0}{3}$

$\complfull{a}{ - b}$

$\complfull{0}{3}$

$\complfull{\frac{-1}{12}}{-3}$

$\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-\dfrac12}$

$\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{\dfrac12}$

\end{document}


(I rewrote the answer to solve the OP's formatting issue with more generality.)
Here's a LuaLaTeX-based answer. It makes no assumptions about the contents of the real and imaginary parts of the complex number, other than that the imaginary part may start with a - symbol. (In contrast, a leading + symbol is not allowed; however, this restriction could be weakened if need be.)
The \complfull macro may be used in both text and math mode. \complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3} poses no problems -- as long as the amsmath package, which provides the macro \dfrac, is loaded.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\ensuremath' macro
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env. and '\luastringN' macro

\begin{luacode}

function complfull ( re , im ) -- inputs: real and imag. parts

  -- begin by stripping off any leading whitespace from 'im'
  im = im:gsub ( '^%s*' , '' ) 
  im = im:gsub ( '^%-%s*' , '-' )

  if im == '0' then -- real number
    return re 
  else 
    if re == '0' then -- imaginary number
      if im == '1' then 
        return 'i'
      elseif im == '-1' then 
        return '-i'
      else 
        return im..'i'
      end
    else -- complex number
      if im == '1' then 
        return re..'+i'
      elseif im == '-1' then 
        return re..'-i'
      else
        if im:sub(1,1)=='-' then 
          return re..im..'i'
        else 
          return re..'+'..im..'i'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

\end{luacode}

\newcommand\complfull[2]{\ensuremath{\directlua{%
  tex.sprint(complfull(\luastringN{#1},\luastringN{#2}))}}}

\begin{document}
\complfull{1}{0}; 
\complfull{0}{1}, 
\complfull{0}{-1};  
\complfull{1}{1}, 
\complfull{1}{-1}; 
\complfull{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}},
\complfull{\frac{1}{2}}{-\frac{1}{2}};
\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{\exp(7)},
\complfull{\dfrac{-1}{12}}{-3}.
\end{document}

